# How do i make background image move programatically

Tags: ios

i'm using Xcode 5.1.1 single view application

Think of a game like Swing Copters. As the copter guy flies up the background clouds fall down the screen giving you the illusion that the copter is flying up through the sky. I need to make that programatically.

A storyboard's height is 568. So i manually made an image that's 2000 long. Then in the implementation file in my -(void)moveplatform method i added and it worked

```
forest.center=CGPointMake(forest.center.x, forest.center.y +platformDown/7);
if (forest.center.y > self.view.bounds.size.height +forest.bounds.size.height/7) {
    forest.center=CGPointMake(forest.center.x, forest.center.y -600);
}
```

However, i want to do this programatically instead of manually because another view controller is being negatively affected by me manually putting in image.

How do i do this programatically?

Comment: Aren't you already doing it programmatically?

Comment: Not exactly. By programatically i meant first use  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];   to put in the background image programmatically and then use code to move that background image based on how much my character is moving in the game.